# CSS DIVs Break On Zoom

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling with this for over 4 hours now and I can't figure this out.
Usually when I design a site I always have it centered so I never face the problems were divs break out of the layout.

**ISSUE 1**

I have a sidebar on the left, followed by a content block and then a sidebar on the right.
Each sidebar should be 180px wide and the content block should fill the empty space between those two sidebars.

I can't even get them to float next to eachother now, I could do so before but I am really getting crazy.

Even if I do get them to float next to eachother, when I zoom in the page the content block breaks layout and falls down below the left sidebar it is so super annoying I never had this issue before.

**ISSUE 2**

The div Block at the header should automatically size between the two logos, similar to what i need for the content_wrapper, how can i do this?

---

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="left_logo" class="logo"></div> <!-- Logo on the Left -->
    <div id="block">This is a block</div> <!-- Div block inbetween the two logos -->
    <div id="right_logo" class="logo"></div> <!-- Logo on the Right -->
</div>
<div id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="left_sidebar" class="sidebar">Left Sidebar</div>
    <div id="middle_content">Middle Content</div>
    <div id="right_sidebar" class="sidebar">Right Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    background-image: url('../bg.jpg');
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-image: url('../avatar.jpg');
    border: solid 1px;
}

#block {
    border: solid 1px;
    float: left;
}

#left_logo {
    float: left;
}

#right_logo {
    float: right;
}

#content_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 180px; 
    float: left;
}

#middle_content {
    min-height: 500px; 
    width: 100%; 
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to note

- move the `#right_sidebar` before the `#middle_content`
- `#right_sidebar` must float right not left
- `#middle_content` must not float and not have `width: 100%`
- if you want to have the `#middle_content` in its own column, i.e. not float below the left and right sidebar, add `margin-left` and `margin-right`

The same applies to `#header`.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FM9y8/1/) for how this could look like.

Although it's several years old, there's a nice overview of basic layout schemes with CSS at http://www.thenoodleincident.com/tutorials/box_lesson/boxes.html